# Tabular.vim: Align words before delimiter

Tags: regex, vim, tabular

I want to go from

```
some.procedure(argOne => var1,
    arg2 => var2,
   argThree => var3)
```

to

```
some.procedure(argOne   => var1,
               arg2     => var2,
               argThree => var3)
```

I tried to run `:Tabularize /=>/l1c1l0`, but it won't align the arguments to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to align both the word before the hash rocket and the hash rocket:

```
:Tabularize/\(\w\+\ze\s\+=>\|=>\)/l0l1
```

Comment: Oh, I need to escape the special regex characters on the string, that's why my efforts were being foiled. Thanks!